# svn diff fails with 'Cannot display: file marked as a binary type.' even though file has svn:mime-type propset to "text/plain"

Tags: svn

> > svn propget svn:mime-type myFile.xml
> >
> > text/plain

SVN diff output.

> > svn diff myFile.xml
> >
> > ## Index: myFile.xml
> >
> > Cannot display: file marked as a binary type.
> >
> > svn:mime-type = application/xml

Tried capturing diff using "svn diff --force", do not see the new changes in diff with this command.

Expected: SVN diff return contents in text format.
Actual: SVN diff fails to capture with "file marked as a binary type"

Comment: Did you try `text/xml`? Could you provide output of `svn status`?

Comment: no luck with text/xml as well. 

[prompt]$ svn st
>> MM      myFile.xml

Comment: Could you try to commit it (the second  `M` means properties modified) and after edit and see the diff?

Comment: do not have the provision to commit the changes unless the changes are approved.